# Cartthrob Order Manager Settings

Tags: cartthrob, mysql

Under the database table `exp_cartthrob_order_manager_settings` I have updated the 'cp_menu' to 'no' but the eCommerce tab is still showing in the control panel. I would like to remove the tab but does not work in the settings or by updating the database. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have `cp_menu` set in your EE or CT config file somewhere? That would override what the DB and CP are set to.